# If we send charitable rewards to the deceased, will they be notified of who has sent a charitable reward to them?

Tags: death, sadaqah

If we send charitable rewards to the deceased, will they be notified of who has sent a charitable reward to them?  Therefore, would sending charity on their behalf would be best for them?

As the prophet did approve different forms of charity on behalf of the deceased. I.e. a man gave his garden on behalf of his deceased mother.

I've surfed the web and found no answer.